# How I have to encode url for Facebook sharing

Tags: php, facebook, share

I am using a JScript code like this:

```
shareLink = function (link) {

    FB.ui({
        method: 'share',
        display: 'popup',
        href: link,
    }, function(response){});

}
```

and it is called in a line like this:

```
<?php
$sharedata = " ... parameters ... "
?>

<a href="javascript:shareLink('http://<?php echo $site; ?>/?v=<?php echo rawurlencode($sharelink); ?>');">
```

so, the destination script trasform parameter by using:

```
$str = rawurldecode($_GET["v"]);
```

the problem is when the url has a "+" character
using rawurlencode it its converted to "%2B"

```
zcu0xci%2FFMH2%2B7cLDPVP%2BgD7%2FwQJ%2FFT2Bw%3D%3D
```

but facebook change only "%2B" into "+" sign again:

```
zcu0xci%2FFMH2+7cLDPVP+gD7%2FwQJ%2FFT2Bw%3D%3D
```

and my script does not recognize it

**EDIT:**

if I echo the "v" parameter I get

```
zcu0xci/FMH2 7cLDPVP gD7/wQJ/FT2Bw==
```

instead of

```
zcu0xci/FMH2+7cLDPVP+gD7/wQJ/FT2Bw==
```

**SOLUTION:**

the solution I've found is to replace space by "+" before decode

```
$str = str_replace(" ","+",$str);
```

Comment: Your solution is, I believe, unnecessarily complicated. Please see my answer below!

Comment: it does not work

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `rawurldecode()` on elements of the `$_GET` *super-global* variable.  PHP decodes URL data for you.

In addition, you should generally use `urlencode()` to encode query string data.  If you investigate the difference between these two functions, you'll see that [urlencode()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) will translate any space character to the "+" character.  This could possibly be the problem you're experiencing.

I'm having difficulty understanding the remainder of your question. You may need to work on your phrasing.

Comment: i'm sorry if you dont understand, english is not my mother tongue

Comment: @LeonardoJavier, no worries!  I hope I was at least able to help a little.

Comment: using or not the rawurldecode() function I have same result, "+" is converted into a space